# slicing the last n characters in string after final whitespace

Tags: bash, string

A string is returned by `myString=$(some_command)`.

The resulting value of `myString` looks like:

```
there are spaces in this line.
```

**What specific `bash` command can be typed to extract only the last `n` number of characters after the final space in the resulting value of `myString`?**

For the example value of `myString` shown above, I would want to extract the 5 characters `line.`

However, for a different value of `myString` like "this line has many spaces.", the desired sliced output would be `spaces.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a variable

```
myString='there are spaces in this line.'
```

you can remove the longest leading component ending in a space using the [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) `${myString##* }` e.g.

```
$ myString='there are spaces in this line.'
$ echo "${myString##* }" 
line.
$
$ myString='this line has many spaces.'
$ echo "${myString##* }"
spaces.
```

Comment: Your code works.  Thank you.  But here is the major problem that I see: Your code looks like black magic because it does not explain HOW it works.  This means that a reader is not easily able to apply the underlying concepts to other problems.  Are you willing to add a paragraph or two explaining HOW your code works?

Comment: @CodeMed I have now added a linked reference - I hope that provides the additional explanation that you want